# Reading .mdb files with UCanAccess returns column names in all UPPERCASE

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm in the middle from migrating from the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver to the UCanAccess driver.

In doing this, I'm facing the following problem: The UCanAccess driver returns all columnames in UPPERCASE, but I need them to be CamelCase.

Any ideas?

Thx!

Comment: UCanAccess is based on hsqldb, which returns table and column names in upper-case when you call DatadaseMetaData or ResultSetMetaData methods. That's because these names are internally registered, in hsqldb, as all uppercase. Instead, with an SQL statement , you can refer to a table or a column using a case insensitive identifier. Also in ResultSet.getXXX(<columnLabel>) methods, the parameter columnLabel is evaluated as case insensitive.  So, exactly, why do you need the CamelCase?

Comment: ...we ar..? Is it something like an ORM reverse engineer or do you use a generic map? Anyway, I think I'll change this behavior (if it's possible with an internal UCanAccess remapping) in the 2.0.5.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Sadly, the project I'm working on, uses the returned columnames as properties. But good to know, that the "problem" is in hsqldb. We'll start looking in an other direction for a solution. (lol, I had submitted the first comment by accident, wanted to change it, but was pulled away befor I could commit)

Answer (score 3):

With [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) version 3.x, released in August 2015, `ResultSetMetaData` now returns the column names in mixed case if that is how they are defined in the database. (That is, they are no longer forced to UPPERCASE.)

---

*(Original Answer)*

Since UCanAccess depends on Jackcess, one possible workaround might be to retrieve the column names from Jackcess itself. The following code, using UCanAccess 2.0.4 and Jackcess 2.0.4, ...

```java
package ucanaccesstest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;

public class UCanAccessTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dbFileSpec = "C:/Users/Public/mdbTest.mdb";
        String tableName = "ucaTest";

        // UCanAccess
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbFileSpec)) {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [" + tableName + "] WHERE False");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("Column names as reported by ResultSetMetaData:");
            for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
            }
            rs.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // Jackcess
        try (Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File(dbFileSpec))) {
            Table tbl = db.getTable(tableName);
            System.out.println("Column names as reported by Jackcess:");
            for (Column col : tbl.getColumns()) {
                System.out.println(col.getName());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

}
```

... produces the following console output:

```
Column names as reported by ResultSetMetaData:
ID
FIELD1
FIELD2

Column names as reported by Jackcess:
Id
Field1
Field2
```

Comment: I'm working to avoid  the need of workarounds.
I can map the namming internally, in UCanAccess,
so asap UCanAccess will have this feature.

Comment: @GordThompson : I am facing a similar situation where I my `ms-access  2013` table is not returning the columns in the way it is defined in the db (it is **jumbled**). I am using `commons - logging 1.2`, `hsqldb`, `jackess 2.1.1`, `ucanaccess 2.0.9.5`, `commons-lang 2.6` and `rs2xml` for getting the `ResultSet` to a `Jtable`. . So, could you please suggest me how to construct it to get the column properly ?

Comment: @mustangDC - Try using the [setColumnOrder](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/Database.html#setColumnOrder(com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Table.ColumnOrder)) method of the Jackcess `Database` object to retrieve the columns in display order. If you need further assistance please post a new question tagged as "Jackcess".