# Solr templated sql print nothing in dataimport

Tags: solr, ucanaccess

I have the following dataimport configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver" type="JdbcDataSource" url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/feqh/main.mdb;memory=false" />

<document>
    <entity name="Book" 
            query="select bkid AS id, bkid AS BookID,bk AS BookTitle, betaka AS BookInfo, cat as cat from 0bok">
                   <field column="id" name="id"/>
                   <field column="BookID" name="BookID"/>
                   <field column="BookTitle" name="BookTitle"/>
                   <field column="cat" name="cat"/>    
        <entity name="Category"
                query="select name as CatName, catord as CatWeight, Lvl as CatLevel from 0cat where id = ${Book.cat}">
                    <field column="CatName" name="CatName"/>
                    <field column="CatWeight" name="CatWeight"/>
                    <field column="CatLevel" name="CatLevel"/>
        </entity>

    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

This dataimport is failed due to the following error from the log:

> Unable to execute query: select name as CatName, catord as CatWeight,
>   Lvl as CatLevel from 0cat where id = Processing Document # 1

When I replace `${Book.cat}` with any fixed number such as 128, the import works fine.

So it seems that ${Book.cat} does not printout any value. The database that I import data from is MS Access database mdb using [ucanaccess](/questions/tagged/ucanaccess) version **2.0.9**. I'm using Solr 4.9.0 on Java8. How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unknown reason I found that the column name should be written in Upper case in the template, so `${Book.cat}` should be `${Book.CAT}` I said unknown because I'm sure that the column
 name in the database is written lower case `cat`.

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962667/reading-mdb-files-with-ucanaccess-returns-columnames-in-all-uppercase. If solr internally uses  resultset metadata (in a case sensitive manner), this should be the answer to your doubts. I want to avoid those kind of issues, but implementing the right case in the metadata without in a trasparent way (without side effects) is a tricky task. It will be done in ucanaccess 3.x.x.